# An unexpected error is displayed in Artifacts page of Azure Devops

Tags: azure, devops, artifacts

I wanted to start creating a feed in Azure Devops with my subscription.
But when I click on the "Artifacts" menu, I get this error.
Does this happen to everybody ?

[image: Error when clicking on artifacts menu]

Answer (score 13):

So I guess it's an issue with a preview feature they are trying to implement. So we need to turn it off for the moment.
User Settings > Preview Features > New Artifacts (Feeds)

[image]

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/XHlBsDI.png - I tried by disabling and enabling and felt no more difference.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this error occurs due to browser issues like:

- Check the Web portal supported browsers of Azure DevOps from this [Microsoft Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/server/compatibility?view=azure-devops#web-portal-supported-browsers).
- Try resetting the cookies, cache, and Application storage in the browsers > Re-login to the Azure DevOps application/site and check:

Edge Browser > Azure DevOps Site > Inspect > Application > Storage > clear storage

(Same to other browsers like Chrome > Open Azure DevOps Site > Developer Tools > Application > Storage > Clear Storage)

[image]

- Refresh the browser several times, Close and re-login still if the issue exists.

If the issue still persists every day, then please raise a ticket in the [official Developer community](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/report?space=21&entry=problem) Site for Azure DevOps issues provided by Microsoft which can be dealt by Microsoft Engineering Teams.

Comment: I have resetted everything in my browser. That didn't fix the issue.
But I went to developper community and found that we need to turn off New Feed Features.

User Settings > Preview Features > New Artifacts (Feeds)