# Azure devops Artifacts - failed to get feed

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-artifacts

I have an error when im trying to see Artifacts in azure devops,
just clicking the option "artifacts" and the screen shows the following message :
An unexpected error has occurred - Failed to get feed .

help anyone ?

Answer (score 4):

> An unexpected error has occurred - Failed to get feed .

Based on the error message, this could be related to new Artifacts feature.

You can disable the **New Artifacts (Feeds) Experience** in Preview feature to alleviate this issue.

[image]

Comment: Where is this setting found ?

Comment: Never mind: found it: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72675009/170169

Comment: Glad to know that you can find the settings. May I know if it can work when you disable the option?

Comment: Yes. Works fine afterwards